# Immutable members on objects

Tags: f#

I have an object that can be neatly described by a discriminated union. The tree that it represents has some properties that can be easily updated when the tree is modified (but remaining immutable) but that are relatively expensive to recalculate.

I would like to store those properties along with the object as cached values but I don't want to put them into each of the discriminated union cases so I figured a member variable would fit here.

The question is then, how do I change the member value (when I modify the tree) without mutating the actual object? I know I could modify the tree and then mutate that copy without ruining purity but that seems like a wrong way to go about it to me. It would make sense to me if there was some predefined way to change a property but so that the result of the operation is a new object with that property changed.

To clarify, when I say modify I mean doing it in a functional way. Like (::) "appends" to the beginning of a list. I'm not sure what the correct terminology is here.

Comment: Can you maybe give a representative code example of what you're trying to do? From your description it sounds like you want to eat the cake and have a cake too...

Comment: Since my actual use case is a bit convoluted and I'm still figuring it out, here's a simplified example. Say you have a fraction and you decide to represent it as a tuple of integers. Now, let's imagine that calculating the decimal representation of a fraction is very expensive. I can have a function addOne that simply does (x, y) -> (x + y, y) and since I know what addOne does, I also know that I just need to (+1) the decimal representation. But because my type is just a tuple, there's nowhere to cache that value so I'm forced to recalculate every time and I can't use the (+1) shortcut.

Comment: Because I enjoy just having the fraction as a tuple instead of something like ((x, y), decimal), I decide to store the cache as a member variable. But then, how do I implement my addOne function so it not only modified the tuple, but the member cache as well?

Comment: Ok, let me give you a code example then and you tell me how close I was

Comment: so your +1 function should change the decimal anyway ... err why then is ` ((x,y), decimal)` a problem? - of course something like using your own type fraction might be a better idea - there you can make the decimal value internal

Comment: @CarstenKönig That's what I want to do. I want to have a custom fraction type, but still have the nice properties of discriminated unions. Ideally, I'd implement my addOne function like `addOne Frac(x, y) = Frac(x + y, y) |> modify { decimal = decimal + 1 }`. The modify part is something I made up. It's what I'm looking for in this question.

Comment: what are those "nice features" you want to retain?

Comment: why not use record syntax - it looks like `let modified a = {a with b=c}`

Comment: @JohnPalmer: exactly what I am thinking - we could try to give you this in the answer if you want

Comment: That's actually perfect! Post an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

F# actually has syntax for copy and update records.

The syntax looks like this:

```
let myRecord3 = { myRecord2 with Y = 100; Z = 2 }
```

(example from the MSDN records page - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233184.aspx).

This allows the record type to be immutable, and for large parts of it to be preserved, whilst only a small part is updated.

Comment: the syntax is what you're looking for, but be careful if you want to use the record to store cached values that you may or may not have at a given moment, because it will affect structural equality comparisons on your type.

Comment: I see. This won't be a problem in my case.

Comment: @JohnPalmer Could you elaborate a bit on the "large parts of it will be preserved"? I'm guessing that means that all the values aren't copied, just the structure that holds the pointers is, right? That means that updating one field in a large record is slower than updating one in a small record, right?

Comment: @LukaHorvat - I believe that you are correct - but I have not tested.

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest way to go about it would really be to carry the 'cached' value attached to the DU (as part of the case) in one way or another. I could think of several ways to implement this, I'll just give you one, where there are separate cases for the cached and non-cached modes:

```
type Fraction =
    | Frac of int * int
    | CachedFrac of (int * int) * decimal
    member this.AsFrac =
        match this with
        | Frac _ -> this
        | CachedFrac (tup, _) -> Frac tup
```

An entirely different option would be to keep the cached values in a separate dictionary, this is something that makes sense if all you want to do is save some time recalculating them.

```
module FracCache = 
   let cache = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<Fraction, decimal>()

   let modify (oldFrac: Fraction) (newFrac: Fraction) =
       cache.[newFrac] <- cache.[oldFrac] + 1 // need to check if oldFrac has a cached value as well.
```

Basically what memoize would give you plus you have more control over it.